# DyanamoDB PHP SDK Store multiple string values for primary key

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am parsing an external JSON datasource which gives me list of Bus Stop codes and corresponding street names.

Data is presented to me in this format:

```
BusStop01 Street01 Description22 Latitude31 Longitude44
BusStop12 Street05 Description72 Latitude13 Longitude32 
BusStop22 Street34 Description28 Latitude43 Longitude21
...
```

I am able to parse the JSON and use the AWS PHP SDK and store this in DynamoDB in the same format with BusStop a the primary key. Here's the relevant section of my code:

```
$putResponse = $client->putItem([
'TableName' => 'TABLEDUMMY01',
'Item' => [
     'BusStopCode'       => ['N'      => $BusStopCode        ], // Primary Key       
     'RoadName'          => ['S'      => $RoadName           ],
     'Description'       => ['S'      => $Description        ],
     'Latitude'          => ['S'      => strval($Latitude)   ],
     'Longitude'         => ['S'      => strval($Longitude)  ]            
     ]
]);
```

What I really want to achieve is to store the same data in this format using *StreetName* as the *Primary Key*:

```
StreetName01, BusStop01, BusStop33, BusStop43...
StreetName02, BusStop23, BusStop29, BusStop67...
```

**NOTE**: The external datasource gives me only 50 values in one API call, hence I need to be able to append/push new BusStop IDs in to existing *Street Names* on DynamoDB

Comment: You want StreetName as primary key instead of busStopName or combining both keys?

Comment: I think you need "street name" as hash key and "Bus Stop Ids" as range key. This model would allow you to push "Bus stop ids" to existing "street names". Please note that combination of "street name" + "bus stop ids" must be unique. Also, in terms of query access pattern, you would need "street name" to query the database rather than scan or you may need to create global secondary index (GSI) based on your query access pattern.

Comment: @HarshalBulsara: I just want the StreetName as primary key with all BusStop IDs in that street as column values in that row. And more importantly, I am seeking guidance for the PHP code to put items in that order using AWS SDK

Comment: @notionquest:  Do I really need a hash+key? I am new to DynamoDB and not sure if I need more than a simple table. (I understand how to implement this using mySQL but Dynamo is a bit confusing).

Comment: @Anand, most important thing before designing any schema for NoSQL would be to get all the list of query(at least major ones) you will do on that table, that will helpful in designing the schema properly

Comment: Yes, hash + range key is basically a primary key. I think you need street name + stop ids as keys. I would design this way for this use case based on my limited understanding of your requirement.